# How do I return the smallest value by using an operator between a list and a float in a function?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to write a function that takes a list of records as a parameter and finds the one with the samllest value to return in a loop.

here is my code below:

```
def get_min_sale_records(records):

  min_price = records[0]
  for min in records: 
      if min[3] < min_price:
        min_price = min
  return min_price
```

for this line "if min[3] < min_price:" it says that I cant use the < operator between a float and a list. I am new to python, please explain your answers.

Comment: Use the built-in `min()` function along with a `key` function that gets the field you want to compare.

Comment: `min(records, key = lambda r: r[3])`

Comment: In your code, `min[3] < min_price` should be `min[3] < min_price[3]`

Comment: thankyou the last one helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as someone said in the comments
the bug in your code is that you compare min[3] with min_price  instead of min_price[3]

```
def get_min_sale_records(records):

  min_price = records[0]
  for min in records: 
      if min[3] < min_price[3]:
        min_price = min
  return min_price
```

this is a working version of your code
but I would recommend using the min function with key

```
def get_min_sale_records(records):
    min(records, key = lambda r: r[3])
```

if you insist to use the first solution I would recommend using the name record instead of min since min is a name of a built-in function in python

```
def get_min_sale_records(records):

  min_price = records[0]
  for record in records: 
      if record [3] < min_price[3]:
        min_price = record 
  return min_price
```